# Defining an alert based on the comparsion to other metric

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

is it possible to create an alert in Azure which is based on the calculation between two metrics?

Specifically I would like to compare incoming bytes to outgoing bytes on event hub and when the difference is greater than some threshold value I would like to send an alert.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with the default Azure Monitor setup, but if you send the data to Log Analytics you would be able to write a custom query using Kusto to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you also help me with this setup because what I did so far is that I created new diagnostic settings in which I'm sending all metrics to newly created log workspace. I'm not sure if that's the correct way of setting it up.